# Book recommendations about web service

Tags: wcf, web-services, asmx

I need a book/article about web service, which I hope to cover the evolution of web service technologies such as from `asmx` based approach to `WCF` based one (and possibly other relevant things).

My background is like this:

- Familiar with .NET, ASP.NET;
- Totally new to web service concept and distributed computing;

Please recommend something to me.

Many thanks.

### Update

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296040/wcf-for-the-totally-clueless) seems to solve my problem.

Comment: You should simply ignore ASMX. It's simply the old technology. It has been replaced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [wcf](/questions/tagged/wcf) information page at https://stackoverflow.com/tags/wcf/info.